# Creating Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, youtube, youtube-api, beautifulsoup

I can parse a file that looks like:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpQNMBzwShs"></a>
```

but when I give it just:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpQNMBzwShs
```

It errors.

How do I turn `soup` into a list skipping the `# extract youtube video urls` process entirely, which is what I think I need to do?

```
# parse bookmarks.html
with open(sys.argv[1]) as bookmark_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(bookmark_file.read())

# extract youtube video urls
video_url_regex = re.compile('http://www.youtube.com/watch')
urls = [link['href'] for link in soup('a', href=video_url_regex)]

# extract video ids from the urls
ids = []
for video_url in urls:
    url = urlparse.urlparse(video_url)
    video_id = urlparse.parse_qs(url.query).get('v')
    if not video_id: continue # no video_id in the url
    ids.append(video_id[0])
```

When I `print soup` it gives me a list of urls that I thought I could just extract the video id's from using the existing code and `urls = soup` but when I do that it says I have only 1 url.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question - as it is - is quite puzzling: `beautifulsoup` is used to parse an XML trees, but you seem you are trying to parse a simple text file instead?

If this is the case, assuming the file has one URL per line you simply have to load it line by line and assign its content to `urls`

```
urls = open('<your-filename-here>').readlines()
```

then you can simply use the loop you already have:

```
# extract video ids from the urls
ids = []
for video_url in urls:
    url = urlparse.urlparse(video_url)
    video_id = urlparse.parse_qs(url.query).get('v')
    if not video_id: continue # no video_id in the url
    ids.append(video_id[0])
```

...but maybe I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: that was it!! I'm still starting out and that was really helpful thank you. Not sure if I'm supposed to post this here but when I made that change I now get a different error.

Comment: I've started a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422302/python-youtube-gdata-api-broken-after-small-change) Thanks @mac